# how to change arrow position of select element in html for rtl

Tags: html, html-select, opera

I want to change the arrow position of a select element to the left side because now it's covering the string, as this is RTL writing system.
I did a lot of things by CSS and HTML5 but it's still not working very well.

```css
.spec {
  direction: "rtl";
}
```

```html
<label for="">التخصص</label><br />
<select dir="rtl" name="" class="spec">
  <option dir="rtl" value="nursing"> تمريض </option>
  <option dir="rtl" value="lab">مختبر</option>
  <option dir="rtl" value="pharm">صيدلة</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Seems to work for me in Chrome

Comment: but not working in opera

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to move it if you don't want. Just add

```
select{
   padding-left: 15px; /*exact width of default arrow down*/
   box-sizing: border-box; /*optional if you also want to play with width property*/
}
```

Also please add the browser where you encounter this issue.. in Chrome, Firefox and IE (all last versions works good without any extra CSS)

Comment: i am using opera browser , but in chrome working as i want